# Carbon Fields use in custom plugin class

Tags: plugins, custom-field

I have plugin which so far has no functional, and has a structure

```
class Test
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}

$wpTest = new Test();
```

I need to use Carbon Fields, and when I installed this library, I changed the structure according to the instructions, only with the adaptation to OOP

```
use Carbon_Fields\Container;
use Carbon_Fields\Field;

class Test
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'carbon_fields_register_fields', array( $this, 'crb_attach_theme_options') );
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( $this , 'crb_load' ) );
    }

    public function crb_load()
    {
        require_once( 'vendor/autoload.php' );
        \Carbon_Fields\Carbon_Fields::boot();
    }

    public function crb_attach_theme_options()
    {
        Container::make( 'theme_options', __( 'Plugin Options', 'crb' ) )
        ->add_fields( array(
            Field::make( 'text', 'crb_text', 'Text Field' ),
            ) );
    }

}

$wpTest = new Test();
```

But it does not work, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question. From the part, the problem was that I connected the `vendor/autoload.php` after accessing the `__construct()`.

An example of solving this task below

```
use Carbon_Fields\Container;
use Carbon_Fields\Field;



class PluginOption
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once( 'vendor/autoload.php' );
        \Carbon_Fields\Carbon_Fields::boot();
        add_action( 'carbon_fields_register_fields', array( $this, 'crb_attach_theme_options') );
    }

    public function crb_attach_theme_options()
    {
        Container::make( 'theme_options', __( 'Plugin Option', 'crb' ) )
        ->add_fields( array(
            Field::make( 'text', 'crb_text', 'Text Field' ),
            ) );
    }

}

$wpTest = new PluginOption();
```